# Empty lightbox when pdf confugered save file in firefox

Tags: php, firefox, pdf, joomla, joomla2.5

I am using joomla 2.5 with [ROXBOX](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/multimedia/multimedia-display/rokbox?com_jed_review_307_limitstart=30) plugin and using this showing the PDF's in lightbox. I am facing problem when user configured Firefox auto download PDF files.

When Firefox configured as save PDF instead of open it in browser the light box stays blank and file started download. As we can not have control on browser, is there any way show any message when Firefox auto download for PDF is enabled?

Please Help!!

Comment: Hi Piyush! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want the PDF to display in the browser, rather than forcing a download. If that is the case, try setting the `Content-Disposition` header with a value of `inline`. and `'Content-type` to `application/pdf`.

```
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="the.pdf"');
```

You can use PHP to set header as shown above.